# NoSuchFieldError "ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE" when trying to parse json

Tags: java, jackson, jodatime

I want to convert a json string containing a date into DateTime of jodaTime using jackson. Unfortunately I get this error

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE
```

The json object looks like this:

```
{
"add_time": "2017-04-26 14:26:58",
}
```

I have included joda time and jackson as follows in my pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

jackson version is 2.8.8.
I've created my object mapper this way:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
```

Does anybody know what the problem might be? I'm stuck on this for a couple of hours now. I also tried do disable the `DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE` but it does not help.

Answer (score 1):

NoSuchFieldError results from class structure incompatibility of jackson library side, so you need to check the **finally** resolved library versions of jackson series.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was quite straightforward - from the stack trace I found the line in which the issue occurred in JacksonJodaDateFormat line 124:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.cfg.JacksonJodaDateFormat.with(JacksonJodaDateFormat.java:124)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.ser.JodaDateSerializerBase.createContextual(JodaDateSerializerBase.java:95)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.handleSecondaryContextualization(SerializerProvider.java:956)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:536)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.resolve(BeanSerializerBase.java:320)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.SerializerCache.addAndResolveNonTypedSerializer(SerializerCache.java:197)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1177)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:490)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.PropertySerializerMap.findAndAddSecondarySerializer(PropertySerializerMap.java:90)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase._findAndAddDynamic(AsArraySerializerBase.java:312)
```

So after decompiling the file in IntelliJ Idea, I got this:
[image: Screenshot of decompiled Joda serializer class]

I found out that my version of JsonFormat from com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation package doesn't contain the Feature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE. The missing value is actually in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations package, so after I imported the package in maven (make sure you have the same version as your core Jackson import), it all started to work. Here's the import:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Adding `jackson-annotations` dependency solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a custom date time format as the one in your JSON is not what Jackson expects. You can do that easily by a `@JsonFormat` annotation over the field or setter method (No need to disable `ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE`). E.g.

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
DateTime addTime;
```

The date in your example will be parsed as `2017-04-26T14:26:58.000Z`. Which by the way is the default format Jackson expected.

You may look into custom deserializers if you don't want to add annotations but that's more complicated.

Comment: Your approach did not help. I still get the exception.

Comment: A date time format is required for Jackson to parse this date. The exception you are reporting says that `ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE` isn't available in the version of Jackson you are using. But you don't need to disable or enable this with the approach in my answer. So you can just remove this configuration and you won't get this particular exception. If you need to configure this for other reasons then you'll have to confirm you are using Jackson version >= 2.2

Comment: I don't doubt what you are saying. And I tried it. I have added the @JsonFormat and  removed the code that disabled the ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE. Your suggestion probably prevented an error I would have gotten when the exception is solved but for now I still get this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a deserializer for ZonedDateTime? I got the same error as you and solved it with the following code (note: I used Jackson 2.9.2):

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(ZonedDateTime.class, new ZonedDateTimeDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

The ZonedDateTimeDeserializer:

```
public class ZonedDateTimeDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<ZonedDateTime> {
...
@Override
public ZonedDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
    JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
    String zonedDateTime = node.textValue();
    return ZonedDateTime.parse(zonedDateTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss"));
 }
}
```

(I realize I am slightly late for this question, but I hope it can help someone)